# Using > Operator to compare values in excel range throwing exception. Operator not defined for Range

Tags: vb.net

I updated my post and procedure and worked out all of the Operator errors. The procedure now works half as expected, instead of placing the values in column E, it places them on column J. If I change from column E to column B, then it places the values on G. So the issue is that somehow is shifting my values from my required column to 6 columns to the right.

Here is my whole code.

```
  Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
Dim xlWSPosition As Excel.Worksheet = CType(CType(xlWB.Sheets("byPosition"), Excel.Worksheet), Excel.Worksheet)

                   With xlWSPosition

                .Application.ScreenUpdating = False

                '.Columns("E").Insert(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)
                '.Range("E1").Value = "Exemption"
                '.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()

                Dim colValue As Excel.Range
                Dim lngLr As Long
                lngLr = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row



                .Application.ScreenUpdating = True

                For Each colValue In .Range("F2:F" & .Range("F" & xlWSPosition.Rows.Count).End(XlDirection.xlUp).Row)

                    If colValue.Value > 0 Then

                        colValue.Cells.Range("E2:E" & lngLr).Value = "N"

                    Else

                        colValue.Cells.Range("E2:E" & lngLr).Value = "Y"


                    End If

                Next colValue

            End With
       End Sub
```

As you can see in the screenshot, the N value goes to column J instead of E and also, it seems that it goes an additional row down when looking for >0

[image: Current Output]

Should look like this:

[image: Expected Results]

Comment: Should be `dim colvalue as Excel.Range` and `if colvalue.value > 0` You get this error now because VBA was "nice" in that it selected the `.value` even when you didnt explicitly tell it to (you actually just told it a range variable). But in .net, you are required to explicitly write everything out, .net will not assume for you.

Comment: @JasonBayldon Actually this behaviour is not something to be proud of.  The range is a whole reality beyond just Value. Bear in mind that is a reality shared by different programs (all the Office ones, some of them with a different property name for Value depending upon the conditions). Properly defining things help to not being involved in unclear, prone-to-error situations and help to built overall-accounting, scalable systems. Assumptions tend to narrowly-define situations and, potentially, generate wrong frameworks (a while ago discussing about Val function only accepting ".").

Comment: @varocarbas Who said I am proud of anyones behaviour? Once he understands how the range object works, he should be able to modify his varibles to fit the correct scenario (which you did for him already). I was just explaining why his error is occuring now and not in .net, so OP may want to think about writing his code explicitly in VBA like he will have to in .NET

Comment: @JasonBayldon I meant VBA's behaviour (not caring about having written Value or not). But if you were pointing this out just to highlight that everything should be written explicitely in VBA, then I misunderstood you (I thought that you found this option better). We both were saying the same thing.

Comment: @varocarbas Ah, Right. I never understood why VBA was done that way, it makes more sense to code to the properties of the object than assume the object is automatically the value. Perhaps it was envisioned that way so you dont need to understand all the properties...

Comment: @JasonBayldon this is the base for all this kind of things: making everything more intuitive and easy-to-use under the most likely scenario. The problem is that you can rarely think of all the potential situations and thus you tend to provoke problems. Example: Val Function. When they built this function, they thought "We use "." as decimal separator; most of programming languages are built in English; why bothering programmers by forcing them to define the given decimal separator? Let's make our function to just work with ".", future programmers will be grateful to us".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error message because of intending to perform an invalid operation with a `Range` (checking whether it is greater than zero). You should be doing that with the `Value` property, not with the whole `Range`. Here you have a correction of your code which will help you to understand things better:

```
For Each range In .Range("F2:F" & .Range("F" & xlWSPosition.Rows.Count).End(XlDirection.xlUp).Row)
   If(range IsNot Nothing AndAlso range.Value.Trim().Length > 0) Then
      Dim colValue As Double = DirectCast(range.Value, Double)
      If colValue > 0 Then
         .Cells(xlWSPosition.Rows, "E").Value = "N"
      Else
         .Cells(xlWSPosition.Rows, "E").Value = "Y"
      End If
   End If
Next
```

Note that I am assuming that the values in the given cells are of type `Double`; please adapt this bit (the type of `colValue` and the one in `DirectCast`) to the type you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to fix one issue. But now I am getting a type mismatch error on .Cells(xlWSPosition.Rows, "E").Value = "N"

Comment: @JoseM. I have performed a small modification doing the code safer (making sure that the DirectCast line would not trigger any error); but you have to make sure that the information in the cells is what is expected. In any case, it sounds pretty weird to get a type mismatch when writing text to a cell. Hope that everything is right now; if not, I might help you a bit out but you would have to run a step-by-step execution and be clear regarding the exact information in the cells.

Comment: Column E1 has the column Name. From E2 down the column is empty. I will try the new code and see what happens

Comment: @JoseM. I meant the Format of the cells. But it shouldn't really matter because text can be written anyway. If it does not work, please, set a break point on the loop (on Dim colValue) and tell me what you see.

Comment: I updated my code and works half way. I posted some screenshots above with the current results and the expected result. I can't figure out why my results are moving to a different column 6 columns to the right.

Comment: @JoseM. You asked why your code triggered an error; I explained why and fixed your code (without knowing what this code was doing neither what some variables meant). Now you come saying that your code (the one I didn't write) does not do what you want it to do. You are the one who has to make your code work (or I, in case you would have requested help to perform the whole implementation). The problem in your original question has been completely solved and now you should post a new question with what you don't understand.

Comment: @JoseM. in any case, what your pics show does not make any sense: your code writes every time to the same row (lngLr), so it is impossible to output what you are showing in your picture ("Y" and "N" in different rows). Also all the references are to column "E", not "J". In summary: your code does deliver the wrong results (not because of my correction, but because of having built it wrongly) although not what you are showing in your picture. I recommend you to think a bit about what you want/have done and fix the functionalities by your own; otherwise, you would have to post a new question.

Comment: Thank you. I will post another question. As usual, you've been extremely helpful in helping understand VB.net and Excel. Moving from VBA to VB.net was not as easy as I thought.

Comment: @JoseM. I am starting to have my doubts about being really helpful to you as far as you continue asking things which should be more or less clear at this point. VBA is much more difficult than VB.NET as far as in VB.NET you have lots of visual helps while writing code. Office interop is almost a copy of VBA but easier to the programmer... Rather than continue posting questions, perhaps you should intend to get used to the new format (it is really easy). Start with something simple and keep growing it. For example...

Comment: @JoseM. start a new project completely from scratch, add a reference to Excel and open a blank workbook (I guess that you know how to do that, otherwise, take the automation code from MSDN), don't write additional stuff you don't need for anything, just the basics: stored the value of certain cell ("F1") in a variable; then write to this cell... then build a loop going through all the cells of this column, etc. every time just using the code you need, letting visual studio helping you with the suggestions...

Comment: @JoseM. ... I think that you are a bit scared of VS and VB.NET and you shouldn't. The biggest difference (when dealing with Excel) between VB.NET and VBA is that VB.NET is much easier. What you think? will you give a try to the "do-it-yourself" option? Even, if it is helpful for you, at the start, you might prefer to write a macro and convert line by line to VB.NET (ideally by using VS advantages, that is: typing the main object + "." + go through the shown options).

Comment: @JoseM. Anyway... this is just my impression, completely up to you. Thanks for the award. I will keep helping as much as I can.

Comment: VS is a bit intimidating for me. I will give your suggestion a try. Thx